# TranslateAnimation, occur on top

Tags: android, view

I got a question regarding TranslateAnimation. Is it possible to force the the animation to occur 
on top of other views? I'm trying to translate the first child on top of the other elements in a LinearLayout.

I thought setZAdjustment would do the job, but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why that wouldn't work as expected.

Try customizing your `LinearLayout` to one which overrides [getChildDrawingOrder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildDrawingOrder%28int,%20int%29) and thereby force it to draw your animated child last.